# Oracle SQL NVL() Function

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-null

Ques : How do I will select full table with "NVL()" Oracle SQL function

Code :

```
SELECT NVL(ORDERNO, 'AAA') * FROM GNGRB.PRBOOK;
```

Error :

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 30
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The message is pretty straight forward. You are missing an expression, the comma between NVL and star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT NVL(ORDERNO, 'AAA') as NEWORDERNO, p.* FROM GNGRB.PRBOOK p;
```

This selects all rows and columns of the table, and adds another column, called `ORDERNO`, that replaces `null` values in `ORDERNO` with `'AAA'`.

Note that this only works as long as `ORDERNO` is of a string-like datatype: both arguments of `NVL()` must have the same datatype.